# Regression trees and choosing threshold values to minimize mean squared error

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, cart, algorithms

I'm trying to learn a decision tree for a regression problem. Each node of the generated tree, will split by the criterion `variable < threshold` for some threshold value.

For cost function, I have at least provisionally decided on mean squared error. Given a greedy algorithm for building the tree, and a training data set, that *defines* the correct threshold value (as the one that minimizes mean squared error). But there is still the question of how to efficiently find it.

Or as this author puts it: https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-and-regression-trees-for-machine-learning/

> This is a numerical procedure where all the values are lined up and different split points are tried and tested using a cost function. The split with the best cost (lowest cost because we minimize cost) is selected.
>
> All input variables and all possible split points are evaluated and chosen in a greedy manner (e.g. the very best split point is chosen each time).

And indeed, we want to end up with the threshold value that would have been chosen by the above procedure.

But say a given node is looking at a million training cases. Even if you sort them by input value and consider only midpoints between adjacent values, it might be necessary to evaluate the cost function 999,999 times, just to choose a threshold value. One feels it should be possible to do better than that.

What's the most efficient known algorithm for choosing the threshold value?